# Accessing params in tests

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to test that when I have query parameters, I return the correct content based on that parameter.

I have tried:

```
test "find_tags returns tips with the correct tag type" do
  post = fixture(:post)
  tip = Post |> Post.find_tags("tag", "connect"}) |> Repo.all
  assert String.contains? tip.content, "#connect"
end
```

but I get an error. I am uncertain if this is the correct way to access the parameters, or if there is anything else that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in two areas. The final working test is:

```
test "find_tags returns tips with the correct tag type" do
  post = fixture(:post)
  tip = Post |> Post.find_tags(%{"tag" => "connect"}) |> Repo.all |> List.first
  assert String.contains? tip.content, "#connect"
end
```

The param that is passed in needs to be in the format `%{"tag" => "connect"}` instead of `{"tag", "connect"}`. This was taken directly from the parameters listed in terminal when the page was visited on localhost.

The other part that wasn't working is `tip` is a list when using `Repo.all`, so the struct can be accessed by piping in `List.first`. Without this, `tip.content` is not a string and there is an argument error.